# Reload new HTML document in same window in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am trying to build a small groupchat app using Electron where I have a browser window which is rendering `index.html` file and after some IPC queries I want to load a new HTML document (`loggedIn.html`) in the same browser window Here is what I have tried:

In my `index.js` file I have this ipcMain listener which reloads a new HTML document on `user:login` message:

```
ipcMain.on("user:login", (e, user) => {
    subWin.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'loggedIn.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }))
    //subWin.webContents.send("user-loggedin", user);
});
```

subWin is the main window which is rendering `index.html` document,
this is listening fine but it doesn't open the new HTML document but it loads same HTML doc
and here is my `loggedIn.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GroupChat</title>
        <script>
            const $ = require('jquery');
            const elect = require('electron');
            const {ipcRenderer} = elect;
            ipcRenderer.send("user-loggedin", "user");
            $("p").text("user")
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: oldlace;">
        <div>
            <p>this is new user</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "It doesn't" is not a very detailed problem description -- is there any error output in the console or in the DevTools of the `BrowserWindow` etc.?

Comment: have you enabled the `nodeIntegration` as true while creating sub win?

Comment: If not, the IPC event won't be triggered

Comment: @tpikachu , thanks, It solved my problem